# Why are variables defined with 'self' automatically given a ListWrapper() while inheriting from tf.keras.Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am not familiar with `ListWrapper()`, but it is being applied to all list variables created with `self` when my class inherits from `tf.keras.Model`. 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model

This is bad because it is causing an `IndexError` when I use it in certain functions, or even by just passing it through my Tensorflow model. (I am using eager execution)

A small reproduction of the problem can be seen with this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class my_class(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(my_class, self).__init__()

        self.x = [0]
        print(self.x)

model = my_class()
```

Output:

```
ListWrapper([0])
```

Switching the inheritance to be from `object` solves the issue, which is how I know its `tf.keras.Model` that is causing this.

I tried looking it up but can't find anything on this. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Because this is how the tensorflow has "patched" setting attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Do you have a link so I can read up on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in Tensorflow between tf.keras.Model and eager execution. 
This was not "how the tensorflow has 'patched' setting attributes", as suggested by a comment.

This is a link to the closed issue on Tensorflow:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22853

If you have this problem, it should be fixed in the next Tensorflow update.
This bug was in version 1.11.0