# Automatic conversion of list of tensorflow ops inside a Model to ListWrapper

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am examining a tf.keras code and I found out that when inside a custom model.Model instance every list of `tf` ops assigned to a `self` variable is automatically converted to `ListWrapper` object.
An example of this functionality is shown with the code:

```
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import initializers


class CustomModel(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, width, depth, **kwargs):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.width = width
        options = {
            'kernel_size': 3,
            'strides': 1,
            'padding': 'same',
            'kernel_initializer': initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.01, seed=None)
        }
        self.convs = [layers.Conv2D(filters=width, bias_initializer='zeros', name='convs_{}'.format(i), **options)
                      for i in range(depth)]
        self.conv = layers.Conv2D(filters=width, bias_initializer='zeros', name='conv_{}'.format(0), **options)
        self.conv2 = [layers.Conv2D(filters=width, bias_initializer='zeros', name='conv_{}'.format(0), **options)]

        self.depth = depth
```

where if checked (in a debugger for example):

```
type(self.convs)
```

> tensorflow.python.training.tracking.data_structures.ListWrapper

```
type(self.conv)
```

> tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D

```
type(self.conv2)
```

> tensorflow.python.training.tracking.data_structures.ListWrapper

where it can be seen that `self.convs` and `self.conv2` are `ListWrapper` instead of list. On the contrary if the class does not inherit from `Model`:

```
class CustomModel2(object):
    def __init__(self, width, depth, **kwargs):
        # super(CustomModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.width = width
        options = {
            'kernel_size': 3,
            'strides': 1,
            'padding': 'same',
            'kernel_initializer': initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.01, seed=None)
        }
        self.convs = [layers.Conv2D(filters=width, bias_initializer='zeros', name='convs_{}'.format(i), **options)
                      for i in range(depth)]
        self.conv = layers.Conv2D(filters=width, bias_initializer='zeros', name='conv_{}'.format(0), **options)
        self.conv2 = [layers.Conv2D(filters=width, bias_initializer='zeros', name='conv_{}'.format(0), **options)]

        self.depth = depth
```

the usual lists are created:

```
type(self.convs)
```

> list

```
type(self.conv)
```

> tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D

```
type(self.conv2)
```

> list

So, my question is why is this happening? What's the advantages of using `ListWrapper` over list? Also, how can I use this type? I know I can access its members via a `for` loop for example. Are there any other properties I should know about?

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671481/why-are-variables-defined-with-self-automatically-given-a-listwrapper-while) but neither the question nor the answer satisfied me.